# \@ifmtarg seems to fail detecting an empty parameter

Tags: spacing, macros, conditionals

I must be missing something obvious here, but I can't see it.  The `\SetTitle` nacro defines a title along with an extended title. The extended title is printed in parenthesis, if it is provided. Thus `\SetTitle[$\sin$]{Sine Function}` should produce

```
 Sine Function (sin)
```

and `\SetTitle[]{Sine Function}` should produce

```
Sine Function
```

but I get the trailing `()` for some reason.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IfIsEmptyArg}[3]{\@ifmtarg{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
\makeatother

\DeclareMathOperator{\MyOperator}{op}%

\newcommand*{\NameExtended}{}
\newcommand*{\Name}{}
\NewDocumentCommand{\SetTitle}{%
    s%   #1 = UNUSED in this MWE
    O{}% #2 = extended name
    m%   #3 = name
}{% 
    \renewcommand*{\Name}{#3}%
    \renewcommand*{\NameExtended}{#2}%
}%
\newcommand*{\ShowName}{%
    \par\hspace*{1.0cm}\Name
    \IfIsEmptyArg{\NameExtended}{%
        %% Since \NameExtended not provided don't print it. 
    }{%
        ~(\NameExtended)%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
    \SetTitle[$\sin$]{Sine Function}
    \ShowName
        
    \SetTitle[$\MyOperator$]{My Operator}
    \ShowName
    
    \medskip\par
    Following should NOT have trailing "()":
    
    \SetTitle{Sine Function}% Default parameter not specified
    \ShowName
    
    \SetTitle[]{My Operator}% Default parameter specified
    \ShowName
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any reason you don't use the tools from `etoolbox`, they are IMO a lot more powerfull, including methods to see if a macro is really empty. If you look at the examples in the `ifmtarg` manual, none seems to be expanding the argument (haven't looked at the implementation). I tend to use `\ifdefvoid{}{}{}`

Comment: `\NameExtended` is not nothing. You want to test if the *expansion* of it is empty or not: `\expandafter\@ifmtarg\expandafter{\NameExtended}{x}{y}`. Personally like @daleif I also prefer `etoolbox`'s tests…

Comment: xparse's manual suggests \ifblank from etoolbox or the expl3 conditional \tl_if_blank:nTF

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\ifblank` does the same as `ifmtarg`, it does not expand the argument, so `\ifdefempty` or `\ifdefvoid` is better. I tend to use the later

Comment: @daleif true but the need for expansion is self inflicted here `\IfIsEmptyArg{\NameExtended}{%` could be `\IfIsEmptyArg{#2}{%` and then you wouldn't have to expand it.

Comment: @daleif: Thanks. I did not know about the ones form `etoolbox`. `\ifdefempty` and `\ifdefvoid` both seem to work in this case. From etoolbox documentation `\ifdefempty` seems to be what is needed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The `\ShowName` macro (where the `\IfIsEmptyArg{\NameExtended}{%`) test is, does not have parameters, so that won't work.  However, I had tried modifying `\SetTitle` to `\IfIsEmptyArg{#2}{\renewcommand*{\NameExtended}{}}{\renewcommand*{\NameExtended}{#2}}` but that too did not work.

Comment: @PeterGrill I rewrote my LaTeX version of my university letter class using `etoolbox` saved me soo much code and strange expansions.